# Input values of an ANN constructed with keras framework (using theano)

Tags: neural-network, theano, keras

I want to costruct a neural network which will be trained based on data i create. My question is **what form these data should have?** In other words does keras allow neural networks that take strings/characters as input? If not, and only is able to accept numbers in what range should the input/output be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only condition for your input data i.e features, is that it should be numerical. There isn't really any constraint on range but it's always a good idea to do [Feature Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling), [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) etc to make sure that our model won't get confused. Neural Networks or other machine learning methods cannot accept string (characters, words) directly, therefore, you need to first convert string to numbers. There are many ways to do that, most common techniques include [Bag of Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model), [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) features, [word embeddings](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-NLP-RNNs-Representations/) etc. 
Following tutorials (using scikit) might be a good starting point:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html
- https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words